# How to display data from object in zk (zul file)?

Tags: java, properties, frontend, zk, zul

I am using zk framework for my internship. I currently have a controller that goes and fetches a special link from an api and I have to create an IFrame in a zul file and bind this link into this iframe.

I do not know how to dynamically bind data either from an object, a modal or a properties file.

```
<div id="iframe-div" height="100%" style="background: #ccc;">
    <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://thisIsTheLink.com"/>
</div>
```

is there something similar as src="{mylink}" in zk as they do in other front end frameworks? Is it possible to dynamically bind data in zk framework?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. I recommend using MVVM binding.

zul file:

```
<window viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.example.IndexVM')">
    <div id="iframe-div" height="100%" style="background: #ccc;">
        <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="@load(vm.includeSrc)" />
    </div>
</window>
```

view model:

```
public class IndexVM() {
    public String getIncludeSrc() {
        return "https://thisIsTheLink.com";
    }
}
```

You can even [pass parameters to your included file](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/advanced/pass_arguments_to_include_component.html).